# Android: How can I open Android system USB Sharing Network? The activity or the function are both OK

Tags: android

When user connect the phone to a PC or a Mac and open my application, and I want to open the system USB Sharing Network activity or this function.
Hope there's a way to make this come true. Thank you in advance!
edit:
[image]

When I checked the checkbox of USB sharing network the log is : Tethering  setUsbTehering(True)

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent tetherSettings = new Intent();
tetherSettings.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.TetherSettings");
startActivity(tetherSettings);
```